# SQL query error 1054

Tags: sql

when i try to run the following code i get an error telling me "#1054 - Unknown column 'local_media.fullpath' in 'field list' " does anybody know where i have gone wrong, when i check local_media it does have the required column in it.

```
    drop table films;
    create table films SELECT 
    movie_info.title, 
    movie_info.tagline, 
    movie_info.coverthumbfullpath, 
    movie_info.backdropfullpath, 
    movie_info.certification,
    movie_info.runtime,
    movie_info.summary,
    local_media.fullpath,
    movie_info.details_url,
    movie_info.year,
    movie_info.id,
    movie_info.score, 
    movie_info.directors,
    movie_info.actors,
    movie_info.genres,
    movie_info.imdb_id

    FROM movie_info

    LEFT JOIN local_media_to_movie_info

    ON movie_info.id = local_media_to_movie_info.movie_info_id;

    LEFT JOIN local_media
```

any advice would be welcome at this point as it has stopped me progressing any further until this is fixed :(

Comment: You need to remove the semicolon before the last LEFT JOIN statement. And you probably want to put in an 'ON' clause for local_media, depending on what rows you have because as it stands this will create a cross product result

Comment: You terminate your statement with a `;` just before `LEFT JOIN local_media`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong and incomplete. There's a semicolon after the first join, so `local_media` isn't part of your query at all. If you would remove it, the query becomed invalid, because the join on `local_media` is missing an `on` clause.

By the way, there's hardly any point in left joining `local_media_to_movie_info` if you're not going to use fields from it. You only risk getting duplicate results.

Comment: thank you i know i had done something wrong all fixed now and working as normal.